# How to store DateTime value to Database via DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I am trying to save Date only from DateTimePicker to DataGridView in C# however I am getting this sort of error

```
                TransactionRecords TRF = new TransactionRecords();
                TRF.Opacity = 0.00;
                TRF.Show();
                TRF.outgoingChequeRecordsTableAdapter.Fill(TRF.transcationRecordsDataSet.OutgoingChequeRecords);
                TRF.Hide();

                TRF.outgoingChequeRecordsBindingSource.AddNew();


                int rowindex = TRF.outgoingChequeRecordsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
                //Save Data into Database                
                TRF.outgoingChequeRecordsDataGridView.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                TRF.outgoingChequeRecordsDataGridView[2, rowindex].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
                //    TRF.outgoingChequeRecordsDataGridView[2, rowindex].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");



                TRF.Validate();
                TRF.outgoingChequeRecordsBindingSource.EndEdit();
                TRF.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(TRF.transcationRecordsDataSet);
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction Saved", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

**Error**

> there was an error in part of date format [expression (if known) = ]

My Database Fields

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `DefaultCellStyle.Format`

```
RecordsDataGridView.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";
RecordsDataGridView[2, rowindex].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
```

Comment: Be able to enter a sample of date data

Comment: Do I need to make date time picker format short as well? https://ibb.co/w6V4dYf

Comment: I just realized that in Data Grid View, Date is Appearing as MM/dd/yyyy, how do I fix that? check my screenshot from the link above.

Comment: I have changed my database date field to datetime but still date appears as mm/dd/yyyy and gives same error.

Comment: I edited the answer. Convert dateTimePicker1 date to datetime.

Comment: Same Error, I have added more code. 
Please note that my Date variable is now DateTime before it was string, it used to work fine, but when sorting via date, the results wasnt accurate, this why I changed its datatype from string to datetime, I want to store date as date type variable in database so i can sort properly later via date.

Comment: Also when I changed my data type from string to datetime in database now dates appear as MM/dd/yyyy before it was coming properly as dd/MM/yyyy